# Is there a way to cancel unshare(2)?

Tags: unshare

If I called `unshare ./fooprogram`, is there a way to cancel that unshare while `fooprogram` is running?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve or understand about this but you should probably read the whole man page 2-3 more times if you really need to use this.  That said, the short answer is a very obvious no.

Answer (score 2):

If there would be a way, that would be a kernel vulnerability.

At the time of writing of this comment, the latest kernel (5.7.2), [has documentation on that matter](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/userspace-api/unshare.rst?h=v5.7.2):

> `unshare()` system call adds a primitive to the Linux thread model that
> allows threads to selectively 'unshare' any resources that were being
> shared at the time of their creation.
>
> […]
>
> `unshare()` augments the
> usefulness of Linux threads for applications that would like to control
> shared resources without creating a new process. **`unshare()` is a natural
> addition to the set of available primitives on Linux that implement
> the concept of process/thread as a virtual machine.**

And later continues:

> `unshare()` can be used to implement polyinstantiated directories using
> the kernel's per-process namespace mechanism. Polyinstantiated directories,
> such as per-user and/or per-security context instance of `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` or
> **per-security context instance of a user's home directory, isolate user
> processes when working with these directories. Using `unshare()`, a PAM
> module can easily setup a private namespace for a user at login.**

The documentation does not explicitely says "`unshare()` can not be reverted", but it does mentions that one legitimate use of `unshare()` can be used for security purposes.

One could assume that being able to reverse it would defeat that purpose.

Comment: Actually it is possible, see `setns(2)` and its tool counterpart `nsenter(1)`

Comment: @LL3 if you use `nsenter` after `unshare -U`  you will get a permission denied, because you don't own the namespace.

Comment: Certainly, and also some other combinations (eg. pid namespaces or even a few involving mount namespaces) do not allow "escaping the jail", but there are many other combinations that do allow it, while your answer (as far as I get it) seems to suggest that it's never possible.